# Popup link color is the same as the background

Tags: bug

The font color of the A-tag in the vote pupup when you have lower then 15 repotation is the same color as the background. The text is unreadable unless you select it.

[image: Unreadable text]

Comment: Didn't found the other question because it didn't say anything about a popup, just the comment.

Comment: Honestly your question has a better title, but there's already a lot of activity on the other post.